# Let $G$ be a set and $a, b \in G.$ Then, show that $(G, •)$ is a group where $a•b=ab\div5$.

Tags: group-theory

The above problem was solved for us by my teacher 7 years ago. But, now i have some confusions in the proof. It was done as follows:
(i) closed: Given that $ a•b=ab÷5 \in G \forall a,b \in G$. Hence, closed.
(ii) Associativity: Let $a,b, c \in G$. $a•(b•c)=a•(bc÷5)=abc÷5$ and $(a•b)•c=(ab÷5)•c=abc÷5$. Hence, associative.
(iii) identity: Let $a•e=a \implies (ae÷5)=a \implies e=5$ . Hence identity is $5$.
(iv) Inverse: Let $a•b=e \implies (ab÷5)=5 \implies b=(5\times5)÷a=25÷a$. Hence, inverse is $25÷a$.

Now, my doubt is in proving the existence of identity and inverse. How could we simply cancell the element $a$ both sides to get $e=5$? Because $(G, •)$ is a set with an operation $•$ and to be proved as a group so, we cannot use cancellation law before proving the existance of inverse. Lastly, the identity $b=25÷a \in G$ is also confused as how $25÷a \in G$? Sorry if this is too basic but, i am unable to solve. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have not proved closure, which depends on $G$.  If $G$ is the integers you do not have closure as $1•1$ is not an integer.  If $G$ is the reals you are fine.  The expression $ab \div 5$ is understood to be the usual one in the reals.  Your associativity proof is incorrect because you did not divide by $5$ twice as you should have, but the operation is associative.  For the identity, we just claim (due to some inspiration) that the identity is $5$.  Then the proof you give, and the corresponding one for $5•a$ show that to be the case.  The conclusion should be $5$ is the identity, not identity is $5$.  For the inverse, you are correct you have to know that $25 \div a$ is in $G$, but that would have been solved by closure.  You do need to know what $G$ is to prove closure.

Comment: Thank you sir. Will it be better to call G a set of rational numbers instead of simply calling a set?

Comment: Sorry real number not rational

Comment: It has to be a set for which the operation is closed and that includes $5$.  It could be all the reals, or the positive reals, or the rationals, or the positive rationals, or many other possibilities but you need enough description to prove closure.

Comment: Thank you sir for help.